# Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I've got this error right there but I haven't yet found an answer, mainly because I probably can't see my mistake.

I'm trying to implement a simple WCF service which (through entity framework) retrieves a list from the database which would return to the client consuming the service, but for some reason when I build it I get that error.

The involved codes are the following:

```
public class ReservationService : IReservationService
{

    public List<Reservation> RequestReservationRetrieval()
    {
        using(ReservationRepository reservationRepo = new ReservationRepository())
        {
            return reservationRepo.ObtainReservations();
        }
    }

}
```

and:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IReservationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public List<Reservation> RequestReservationRetrieval();
}
```

I hope you guys can help me, thank you for reading.

Comment: Is the Reservation class also declared public?

Comment: Yes it is: public List<Reservation> ObtainReservations()

Comment: tomasr talking about the Reservation class not a related property.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what it was. Thanks to you both for making me realise such a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because your `Reservation` class isn't public.

Add the 'public' modifier to this class and this error would disappear.

Comment: @krieg If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted answer" (with the green V).